# How to order by records using value from sub query

Tags: mysql, sql

My query looks like as

```
SELECT 
    users.*, 
    (select count(*) 
      from user_actions 
      where status='pending' and user_id = users.id) number_pending
FROM users
order by name
```

I need to show those records first which have `number_pending` count greater than zero. Can you please help me how to achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
u.*, count(a.*) number_pending
FROM users u join user_actions a
on a.user_id = u.id
where a.status='pending' 
order by count(a.*) desc
```

Is this what you are trying to do?